# How to determine the src of an <img> in the public folder from a component in react?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

Can anyone plz help tell me how should I determine the path every time in my react project, as in this scenario what should I add the src=" " path in my menu.js file while the image is in the public/images folder. However I am also using the webpack but don't know how to determine the path correctly as in this example.
Here is my menu.js file Code

```
import React from 'react'

import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const Menu = withRouter(({ history }) => (

  <header>
    <div className="container">
      <nav className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/" className="navbar-brand"><img src="./..public/images/Main_logo.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

));

export default Menu
```

[Here is My project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZCSo.png)

Can you please also clear me how to determine the path and what webpack make a difference in the path determinations?

Comment: if you do not use import then apparently the image links are mapped with your static folders(public)

Comment: And what if you are using the import? And also is the src="/images/Main_logo.png " path is rigth if one is not using the import?

Comment: if you are using import the path is relative to the current file which is importing

Comment: I have tried this but the path is not working still although I am using the imports too.